# PHP Merge Images

Tags: php, image

I Merged two images. First Image will be always white, extension is PNG and size is 1200px X 628px. Size of Second image is 1000px X 495px. But when i merge that images then white image is converted into  black image. and show the background of second image are black. 
Please help me how to solve this problem and change the black image into white image.

Comment: I'm sorry will you please attach what you're getting and what you want output.

Comment: which library is using `GD2` or `ImageMagick` show your code also??

Comment: Please also show us your current code, otherwise we cannot help you

Comment: @ShineDezign you need to make water for image ????

Answer (score 0):

Add below lines to your code, your issue should be resolved,

```
imagealphablending($new_image, false);
imagesavealpha($new_image, true);
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($new_image, 255, 255, 255, 127);
imagefilledrectangle($new_image, 0, 0, $width, $height, $transparent);
```

Just for your reference, full source code for resizing an image,

```
function resize($width,$height) {
      $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
      if ($this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG){
        imagealphablending($new_image, false);
        imagesavealpha($new_image, true);
        $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($new_image, 255, 255, 255, 127);
        imagefilledrectangle($new_image, 0, 0, $width, $height, $transparent);
      }
      imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
      $this->image = $new_image;
   }
```

Comment: Sorry, Girish I may not answering your question, but the function used in above code are for GD only.
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php

Comment: your answer would be correct, but `op` haven't shown code in question also which library is using, if he using `ImageMagick` then this code can works?

Comment: No this is meant for GD only, not for ImageMagick.